# Move zoom controls in Leaflet for R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a Shiny application with multiple leaflet maps. I'd like to move the zoom in/out controls from the top left side of the map to the top right, and I'm not sure how to do this - I'm pretty sure it's by calling `options = leafletOptions()` inside `leaflet()/leafletProxy()`, but I'm unsure of the exact syntax.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  leafletOutput("output1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$output1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery)
  })
  

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(   
  leafletOutput("output1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$output1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery) %>%
      onRender(
        "function(el, x) {
          L.control.zoom({position:'topright'}).addTo(this);
        }")
  }) 
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The code references this: https://markusdumke.github.io/articles/2017/11/customize-leaflet-map-in-r-with-html-css-and-javascript/